# Can you have a GFCI breaker protecting a GFCI receptacle?

Tags: electrical, gfci

We have electrical outlets in two bathrooms on the same GFCI breaker.  I would like to put a GFCI outlet for the only outlet in the guest bathroom so it can be easily reset if tripped.

Can this be done with the GFCI breaker?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it can be done. There is no problem having a GFI fed from another GFI. The only down side is troubleshooting. If something is causing a trip you have to isolate one first to see where the problem is.

My advice is to replace both receptacles with GFI and install a standard breaker. You get the same protection but more convenience. All for only a few dollars more.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the correct solution.

Comment: The other issue is that if you have a ground fault in the guest bathroom, there's no guarantee that the outlet GFCI will trip before the breaker GFCI. You may still have the breaker tripping.

Comment: @DoxyLover hence why he recommends replacing the receptacles with GFCI *and installing a standard breaker* -- so you don't have this problem. Of course you still have the problem of figuring out which outlet tripped if you're on the "second" outlet and it goes out, but that's a relatively minor inconvenience as opposed to having to reset a breaker.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a fan on the bathroom circuit, above the shower, you need to retain the gfci breaker on that circuit.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.SE! Can you provide a source for this?

Comment: This likely depends on the listing and labeling of the fan...